# How to pass String[][] to safeargs?

Tags: java, android

I would like to pass 2d array string as an argument between fragments.

Can't find that option in arguments, so I've changed argType manually in nav_graph.xml

```
<argument
            android:name="rowData"
            app:argType="string[][]" <- changed 
            app:nullable="true" />
```

but then I get an error in self generated args file

```
error: ']' expected
 array = new string[][__array.length];
```

Does safe args supports String[][] or not yet? Should I use normal bundle instead?

Comment: I have no idea how safeargs works, but it would appear you need to add the first dimension (and capitalize `String`)

Comment: What do you mean by capitalize?

Comment: Not supported please check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types)

Comment: Thanks for link. Like i thought, we need to wait.

Comment: `Bundle` doesn't support `String[][]` and Safe Args is just a wrapper around that. How were you expecting it to work?